# Flask- Kerberos remote user server variable not passing

Tags: python, apache, kerberos

I’m having a weird bug with the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable not passing to my routes correctly. My flask app is running on Apache tomcat and using Kerberos authentication.

When I’m on the homepage of my site
`@bp.route(‘/‘)`
The `remote_user` appears in the requests.environ dictionary

However if I try to redirect to a different route the `remote_user` variable disappears from requests.environ dictionary? e.g) `@bp.route(‘/index’)`

I’m able to access both pages and checking the log files it shows the Kerberos authentication is successful .

So I’m not sure what’s going on? Any ideas?